# Laptop wakes up when it is already suspended on closing the lid

Tags: suspend

Laptop is HP pavilion aero, distro is Ubuntu 22.10
So far everything was working great including suspend, except when I put the laptop to sleep while the lid is open using UI and then when I close the lid of a sleeping laptop it wakes up. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.